# Whitelist list of IPs stored as variable?

Tags: nginx

our Nginx config has quite a few `server` and `location` declarations. I'm working on adding some whitelisting using `deny all` and `allow x.x.x.x` directives.  I'm wondering how I can define a global list of IPs and then allow them for multiple sites without listing them all explicitly under every server and location.

In doing some research, it looks like variables are not recommended in the Nginx config due to performance?  However, I'm more worried about user error when updating the whitelist causing security issues.

Here is my goal (pseudocode):

```
set iplist1 [10.1.0.0/16, 100.100.100.100, 200.200.200.200]
#local addresses, remote dev 1, remote dev 2
set iplist2 [10.1.0.0/16, 50.50.50.50, 30.30.30.30]
#local addresses, remote site 1, remote site 2

server {
  server_name devportal.domain.com
  location / {
    allow $iplist1;
    deny all;
  }
}

server {
  server_name siteportal.domain.com
  location / {
    allow $iplist2;
    deny all;
  }
}
```

If it's not recommended to use variables, is there another way to accomplish this?  **The primary goal being that I don't have to update 10 sites when my whitelist changes.**

Answer (score 0):

Put the `set` commands in a file, and include it wherever you want it available.

```
include /path/to/iplist.conf
```

Comment: Was my syntax correct for the set statement?  I literally have no idea how to define an array. Was my guess right?

Comment: Additionally, if I'm using an external file like this, will `nginx -t` also validate this config file syntax?

Comment: And will this impact performance significantly?

Comment: `nginx -t` will follow the includes. If `set` doesn't take an array (I can't recall), you can always `include` a big long list of individual `allow`/`deny` rules.